# Azure CDN Endpoint poiting to Azure Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, azure-traffic-manager

I am evaluating a DR situation within Azure for a website which uses Azure CDN. For the same, one of the approaches I am looking into is to have a CDN endpoint configured to point to Azure Traffic Manager.
Is it a valid design? Can somebody point me to any DR architectures for Azure which combines Azure CDN with Azure Traffic Manager as I am not finding any specific examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of CDN endpoints pointing to Azure traffic manager, you can use Azure Traffic Manager with Azure CDN to load balance among multiple CDN endpoints for failover, geo-load balancing, and other scenarios.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-traffic-manager) provides guidance and an example of how to set up failover with Azure CDN Standard from Verizon and Azure CDN Standard from Akamai profiles.

Main steps:

1. Create two or more Azure CDN profiles and endpoints with different providers.
2. Create an Azure Traffic Manager profile and add your CDN endpoints as **External endpoints** in the Azure Traffic Manager profile.
3. Set up custom domain on Azure CDN and Azure Traffic Manager

Comment: Hi Nancy, Thanks for the answer. I have gone through the post. However, I was wondering since, Azure CDN is supposedly a global one, I would not want to create a different instance and also avoid the hassle of replication, which can be time consuming. Hence was thinking of using one CDN. Another question, may sound a bit stupid, if a region goes down in Azure, would it also limit access to the CDN provisioned in that region.

Comment: I think CDN is a distributed network based on caches. If one primary region is down but there is pre-cached data in the CDN edge server, you're still possible to get the cached data from another region near to your location.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is as follow:

- Deploy web apps (or functions) in two different regions
- Replicate data between the same two different regions (eg. storage accounts, databases)
- Configure Traffic Manager to monitor health of the service on the primary site, if health is degraded, fail over to secondary site

This is pretty well documented in this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/disaster-recovery-dns-traffic-manager